# Any good tutorials on using COM from C#?

Tags: c#, com

For one of a side-projects i need to write a C# app that required to use a third-party INPROC COM object. Unfortunately, C# is not my primary programming language, so my knowledge is a bit limited. Is it any good tutorials available on how to access COM object from C#? The usage of this third-party COM object requires me to create implementation of specified COM interface and supply that implementation into COM object in order for it to function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a good book called [.NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232170X) that I am about to start reading as I want a better understanding of COM interop. Maybe it would be useful for you too, check it out.

> The focus of the book is on COM
>   Interoperability (since it's a much
>   larger subject), and the heart of the
>   discussion is broken down into four
>   parts:
>
> ```
> * Using COM Components Within the .NET Framework
> * Using .NET Framework Components from COM
> * Designing Good .NET Framework Components for COM Clients
> * Designing Good COM Components for .NET Framework Clients
> ```
>
> The scope of the book is just about
>   everything related to using "unmanaged
>   code" in the .NET Framework.
>   Technologies built on top of COM
>   Interoperability are also
>   covered-Interoperability of Windows
>   Forms Controls and ActiveX controls,
>   Interoperability with COM+, and
>   Interoperability with Distributed COM
>   (DCOM). Although Platform Invocation
>   Services is a separate technology from
>   COM Interoperability, there are many
>   areas of overlap, so including in the
>   book is a natural fit. All of these
>   technologies are a core part of the
>   Common Language Runtime and .NET
>   Framework, and will likely be used not
>   only as the path of migration for
>   existing software projects, but for
>   brand new software development for the
>   next several years

Also have a look at this (legally) free pdf ebook [COM and .NET Interoperability](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ComAndDotNetInterop_Book) which you can download from TheServerSide.com. You have to register before you can download, but you can just [bugmenot](http://www.bugmenot.com/view/theserverside.com) if you don't feel like it.

Comment: Isn't this book a little old? It's year 2002, first versions of .net and c# was just released that time.

Comment: Yeah, I wondered that too, but I don't think the way COM interop works has changed since the early days of .NET.

Comment: Yup, it operates the same, or very similarly due to the nature of the model.  Understanding COM is incredibly complex when you get down into it, but incredibly versatile.

Answer (score 40):

I have quite a large .NET <-> COM bookmark collection that I'm dumping below.

The problem is that no one tutorial/article covers all the basics and gotacha's. So you need to go through a couple of them and mix and match, depending on what you want to do.

Here's the best of what I've found so far...

**General .NET COM Articles/Tutorials**

- [.NET - COM Interoperability.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/COM_DOTNET_INTEROP.aspx)
- [COM Interoperability in .NET Framework: Part I.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cominteropnet.aspx)
- [Understanding Classic COM Interoperability With .NET Applications.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/cominterop.aspx)
- [Exposing .NET Components to COM.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/nettocom.aspx)
- [Building COM Objects in C#.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/com_object_in_c_.aspx)
- [Calling Managed .NET C# COM Objects from Unmanaged C++ Code.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ManagedCOM.aspx)
- [Native & Managed Interop Made Simple.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/interop_madesimple.aspx)
- [Using .NET Assembly with COM Client.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/COM_Interoperability.aspx)
- [Moserware: Using Obscure Windows COM APIs in .NET](http://www.moserware.com/2009/04/using-obscure-windows-com-apis-in-net.html)
- [COM Interoperability in .NET Part 1](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=41) [Part 2](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=42)
  [Part 3](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=43)
- [COM Interop Part 1: C# Client Tutorial](http://www.nedcomp.nl/support/origdocs/dotnetsdk/csref/vcwlkcominteroppart1cclienttutorial.htm)
  [Part 2: C# Server Tutorial](http://www.nedcomp.nl/support/origdocs/dotnetsdk/csref/vcwlkcominteroppart2cservertutorial.htm)
- [Calling a COM Component From C# (Late Binding)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/psingh/CallingCOMComponentFromCSharp12022005231615PM/CallingCOMComponentFromCSharp.aspx)
- [Building COM Objects in C#](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives/archive281.html)

**MSDN on .NET & COM**

- [COM Interop Tutorials (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645712(VS.71,loband).aspx)
- [Exposing .NET Framework Components to COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439(VS.80,loband).aspx)
- [Interop Marshaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04fy9ya1(VS.80,loband).aspx)
- [Advanced COM Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd9cdfyx(VS.80,loband).aspx)
- [How to: Register a Component for COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w29wacsy(VS.80,loband).aspx)

**ActiveX in .NET**

- [Internet Explorer ActiveX Control C# Class Library](http://blog.ianchivers.com/wordpress/?p=22)
- [Create ActiveX in .NET Step by Step.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CreateActiveXDotNet.aspx)
- [Dynamically adding ActiveX controls in managed code.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/AxForms.aspx)
- [Exposing Windows Forms Controls as ActiveX controls.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/exposingdotnetcontrols.aspx)
- [Importing and Extending ActiveX Controls in .NET.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/importactivex.aspx)
- [C# Tutorials - ActiveX With C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic38890.htm)
- [CodeGuru: Extensible OLE Property Pages in .NET](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/general/article.php/c8545#more)
- [Writing an ActiveX Control in .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dsandor/ActiveXInNet11102005040748AM/ActiveXInNet.aspx)
- [Hosting ActiveX Controls in the .NET Compact Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx)
- [Hosting Windows Forms Controls in COM Control Containers - O'Reilly Media](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/01/20/winformshosting.html)

Comment: Life saver .... this is exactly what I was looking for .... im not a big fan on the subject but i need to revise this boring topic !!!

thanks for the bookmark dumP !!!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is useful for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The basics are pretty straightforward, and MSDN has good reference information.

In your C# project, use "Add Reference" to add a reference to the COM component.

If you need to implement a COM interface, create a class that inherits from it:

```
class MyClass : IMyComInterface
{
   ...
}
```