# How to call API using C#?

Tags: c#

I am not a c# guy. Needless to say that I don't have experience on this topic.

I bought a software and I installed it on my computer. Now I thought of using some of it's functions on my software(that I make to plan in c#). So I messaged the person who sold me the software and he send me a two page pdf file explaining what to do.

It states:

```
    This software features a COM interface.

    And it goes saying it's API contains a function "stackAPI".

    and the parameters used are apiname type string, apipass type string. 

    Return values type long. 0 for sucess and 1 for error.
```

That's all it states, I tired searching google, it could not help me at all. So how do I start?
when I write the following code on c# it gives me error.

```
string[] apiname;
string[] apipass;
stackAPI(apiname, apipass);
```

I know if I was using dll I would import it as

```
 [DllImport("example.dll"]
```

But no dll is provided.
Do I need to add the path to the folder where the software is installed to call the API ?

Comment: if you're using Visual Studio have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsy826az%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: Have you ever written a simple c# program?

Comment: In a Visual Studio project -> References -> COM and see if its listed (otherwise browse to the DLL) -> Right click the new reference -> View in obj browser

Comment: Seems that you need some background on references and COM Interop. You may look at this question about [COM Interop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630540/any-good-tutorials-on-using-com-from-c) part and this other page for [Managing References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6609kte(v=vs.100).aspx) in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wants to know how I did it. After a week of searching I was able to find the solution today. I wanted to call the function `stackAPI(apiname, apipass);`.

`stackAPI(apiname, apipass)` was the member of `stack.callapi` 
So I wrote:

```
dynamic lifestohack = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("stack.callapi"));
```

than just you can call the function like this.

```
int rv;
string[] apiname;
string[] apipass;
rv=lifestoahck.stackAPI(apiname, apipass);
```

Hope it may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

To get started:

```
using example.dll;
```

Then in your main class:

```
example.CustomService api = new example.CustomService();
var response = api.Dostuff();
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

Comment: No dll is provided. the only thing i have is the software which is installed on my computer and the api documentation which states what is written up in the question.